# Starting Powershell from CMD returns "Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type 'System.String'"

Tags: php, windows, powershell, cmd

I'm trying to use `PowerShell.exe -command $command` in PHP, where the command is a creation for a new user.

I noticed it didn't run, and tried to start it from `CMD` directly (I believe that's what exec(); does).

The code I'm trying to run:

```
powershell.exe -command New-ADUser -SAMAccountName "jajaap" -Instance "Get_ADUser -Identity UserTemplate" -Name "Jan Jaap" -DisplayName "Jan" -Path "OU=Users-NL,OU=Users,OU=Domain-Test,DC=Domain-controller,DC=com" -GivenName "Jan" -Surname "Jaap" -userPrincipalName "jan.jaap@example.com"
```

The error I get is:

> New-ADUser : Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type
>   'System.String' required by parameter 'Path'. Specified method is not
>   supported.

My guess is that I have to escape certain characters in the path string, but I don't know how, or which. Or it might be that there be a `converttostring` kind of function in the CMD? I couldn't find it on Google. On here I saw some examples on how to fix it for mail functions, but I can't figure out how to use those solutions on my code. So please excuse me if this question was already answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you may need to wrap the whole command with curly braces and quotes to make it one string and a scriptblock and prefix the scriptblock with an ampersand as follows:

```
powershell.exe -command "& {New-ADUser -SAMAccountName 'jajaap' -Instance 'Get_ADUser -Identity UserTemplate' -Name 'Jan Jaap' -DisplayName 'Jan' -Path 'OU=Users-NL,OU=Users,OU=Domain-Test,DC=Domain-controller,DC=com' -GivenName 'Jan' -Surname 'Jaap' -userPrincipalName 'jan.jaap@example.com'}"
```

**Per MSDN:**

> The value of Command can be "-", a string. or a script block. If the
> value of Command is "-", the command text is read from standard input.
>
> Script blocks must be enclosed in braces ({}). You can specify a
> script block only when running PowerShell.exe in Windows PowerShell.
> The results of the script are returned to the parent shell as
> deserialized XML objects, not live objects.
>
> If the value of Command is a string, Command must be the last
> parameter in the command , because any characters typed after the
> command are interpreted as the command arguments.
>
> Source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/core-powershell/console/powershell.exe-command-line-help

Comment: Hi Mark, thanks for your quick help. I am trying the way you state above, and get this error: The string is missing the terminator: '.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TerminatorExpectedAtEndOfString

Comment: Are you sure you have the single quote ' at the end of the string?

Comment: I am sure I added that, I copied what you stated above.

Comment: I see the same error actually. Lets flip around the single and double quotes instead. I'll amend my answer.

Comment: Please let me know, I'm fooling around as well, if I figure it out i'll update as well. Thanks for your help thus far! As a first post I got helped way quicker than expected.

Comment: I think you also mistakenly had this `-Instance 'Get_ADUser' -Identity 'UserTemplate'` as this `-Instance 'Get_ADUser -Identity UserTemplate'`. I have amended my answer in both respects, but can't fully test it myself as I don't have access to AD I can experiment on right now.

Comment: Was not aware of that! I've reverted that part.

Comment: Could it be that PS sees a comma separated list and things it is an array object rather than a single string?

Comment: That could've been it. The above solutions worked now.